# php include not working for either of my codes

Tags: php

I have a php include for my header and footer on all my pages as there exactly the same. The problem one does not work and one now that I am with hostgator puts an error page in each page folder the php include is in. The header and footer files are in the main website directory.

The one that I get the error is:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/header.php/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

The one that does not work is:

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

Thanks

Comment: specify the full directory in the `header.php`. See if that helps.

Comment: What do you mean.

Comment: nm, i see your error. get rid of the `/` after `.php`. that should work assuming `https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/header.php` is the correct directory.

Comment: Still error. It says on line 27 which is this line fclose($fp);

Comment: You have a `fclose($fp);`, but you never opened a file pointer with like `$fp = fopen(..);` .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php include_once('header.php');?>
```

use include once may fix
other `fclose($fp);` not require remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the full path to your header.php file

For example:

```
<?php include 'inc/header.php';?>
```

Comment: Thats not an example of a full path, that is an example of a relative path based on the calling php file. A full path would be: `/var/www/webdir/root/blah/header.php` (full path begins with a `/`).